# Can't make NSArray deep copy

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, parse-platform, deep-copy

A user on my app can select filters to narrow down items. Once filters are selected, an `NSNotification` is sent that passes an array of selected filters (`NSString`s) to another view controller.

When I receive a notification, I can extract the array from `[notification userInfo]`. Now, what I want to do is to compare the new filters with those already saved for the user, so that I make a call to the server only if they are different. Here's my method:

```
- (void)applyFilters:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSArray *filters = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"filters"];

    if (showMyItems) {

        if (![[NSSet setWithArray:filters] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"filtersMy"]]]) {

            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:filters] forKey:@"filtersMy"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }

    } else {

        if (![[NSSet setWithArray:filters] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"filters"]]]) {

            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:filters] forKey:@"filters"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm comparing `NSSet`s rather than `NSArray`s because the order of objects/strings is not important. What I try to do then is create a new array and set is as user's new filters via `arrayWithArray:`. So, when the next time the user changes filter selection, I expect that new `filters` array will be different from the one saved for the user (my if statement condition). However, when I NSLog both (new and saved/fetched arrays), they are exactly the same! And therefore the if condition never passes.

My only explanation of this is that the `[NSArray arrayWithArray:filters]` is somehow still pointing to `filters` array.

I even tried the `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:filters]]` suggested on SO and by Apple, but the result is the same.

Can somebody please spot my problem? I'm out of options and ideas...

**UPDATE**:

I have now pasted the full method (above). A bit more background:

- I am using two instances of the same `UIViewController` class
- In one instance, `showMyItems` is set to `YES` (so only the top part of `if` statement is called). In another instance - `NO`, so only the lower part is called
- What is interesting, when `showMyItems` is `NO`, my code works as expected! But when `showMyItems` is `YES`, it doesn't... Although the code is identical.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Too little code to see where the problem lies. Could you isolate the problem in a sample project?

Comment: I've updated the question with the full method and some background details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting my previous method to this solved my problem, although I honestly don't fully understand why.

```
- (void)applyFilters:(NSNotification *)notification {

    NSArray *filters = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"filters"];

    NSString *key = (myItems) ? @"filtersMy" : @"filters";

    if (![[NSSet setWithArray:filters] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithArray:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:key]]]) {

        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:filters] forKey:key];
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];

        [self setUpItemsArrayWithFilters:filters];
    }
}
```

What I basically did is used the same code only once, with only different key used depending on which controller is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:filters copyItems:YES];
```

(The above works for one-level-deep copy)

For deep copying the best way I've found so far is

```
NSMutableArray *deepCopyArray = (NSMutableArray*)CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFDictionaryRef)filters, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));
```

Comment: The above works for me every time. There's something wrong in your code that is not listed in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested some of the code and I've no idea why your If statement is not triggering. Here is the example code:

```
NSArray *newFilters = @[@"A",@"B",@"D"];
NSArray *oldFilters = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"filters"];

if (![[NSSet setWithArray:newFilters] isEqualToSet:[NSSet setWithArray:oldFilters]]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newFilters forKey:@"filters"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not Equal");
}
```

This code will react accordingly for filters changes. I am not exactly sure though why you are creating a new array here `[[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:filters] forKey:@"filters"];`

Comment: It doesn't matter whether I `setObject:` `filters`, `[NSArray arrayWithArray:filters]` or `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:filters copyItems:YES]` - I always get the same behaviour, which is `if` condition not passing. Honestly, I have no idea why it's like this...

Comment: I don't think the problem is in making a copy. You're probably making a mistake somewhere else, it would be great if you could post more relevant code.